# How do I add an object to an array, where the array is a value to a key in a hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

So basically my code is as follows

```
anagrams = Hash.new([])
self.downcase.scan(/\b[a-z]+/i).each do |key|
  anagrams[key.downcase.chars.sort] = #push key into array
end
```

so basically the hash would look like this

```
anagrams = { "abcdef" => ["fdebca", "edfcba"], "jklm" => ["jkl"]}
```

Basically what I don't understand is how to push "key" (which is obviously a string) as the value to "eyk"

I've been searching for awhile including documentation and other stackflow questions and this was my best guess

```
anagrams[key.downcase.chars.sort].push(key)
```

Comment: Had you written, "So basically I've been searching...", I'd have had a screaming fit.

Comment: I did not notice my high usage of the word until you had pointed it out. Stack Overflow, identifying problems in your methods and speech.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess:

```
anagrams[key.downcase.chars.sort].push(key)
```

is right. The problem is your hash's default value:

```
anagrams = Hash.new([])
```

A default value doesn't automatically create an entry in the hash when you reference it, it just returns the value. That means that you can do this:

```
h = Hash.new([])
h[:k].push(6)
```

without changing `h` at all. The `h[:k]` gives you the default value (`[]`) but it doesn't add `:k` as a key. Also note that the same default value is used every time you try to access a key that isn't in the hash so this:

```
h = Hash.new([])
a = h[:k].push(6)
b = h[:x].push(11)
```

will leave you with `[6,11]` in both `a` and `b` but nothing in `h`.

If you want to automatically add defaults when you access them, you'll need to use a [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc), not a simple [`default`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default):

```
anagrams = Hash.new { |h, k] h[k] = [ ] }
```

That will create the entries when you access a non-existent key and give each one a different empty array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your method is supposed to do, but I think the problem is that you don't have an array to push a value onto.

In Ruby you can pass a block to `Hash.new` that tells it what to do when you try to access a key that doesn't exist. This is a handy way to automatically initialize values as empty arrays. For example:

```
hsh = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }
hsh[:foo] << "bar"
p hsh # => { :foo => [ "bar" ] }
```

In your method (which I assume you're adding to the String class), you would use it like this:

```
class String
  def my_method
    anagrams = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }

    downcase.scan(/\b[a-z]+/i).each_with_object(anagrams) do |key|
      anagrams[key.downcase.chars.sort.join] << key
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ahh yes, you are completely right about the default value! I was actually adding the method to a module included in the String class. Also, noticed you added the join method for me. Didn't realize I was missing it until I saw my console! Thank you for the revelations.